# Redirect URL in JSP

Tags: jsp, url, redirect

I am using jsp to develop a web application and it has a page named `product.jsp` and it has a form to add the product information. The add functions just works fine and adds to the MySql table too.

But my problem is even after it adds the below url still stays in the address bar even i refresh.

```
http://localhost:8084/SupipiCrafts_Backup/product_Servlet?txtICode1=ITM002&txtPackNo1=PCK003&txtIName1=Mike+Statue&txtMat1=Wood&txtCat1=Animals&txtSize1=Medium&txtSID1=SUP008&txtSName1=Safa&txtPDate1=2013-02-27&txtQty1=45&txtUprice1=34.0&txtTprice1=1530.0&txtlRate1=34.0&txtfRate1=54.0&txtRlvl1=20&txtLoc1=&txtDesc1=&btnUpdate=o
```

i want to redirect and load the `product.jsp` page after the execution of the add function.
Please help

Comment: So... use response.sendRedirect(). What's the problem?

Comment: @JBNizet I have included it in the servlet. yet the above mentioned url stays. my code is as below

`if(rslt == true)
               {
                 request.setAttribute("flagEdit", "success");
               }
               else 
               {
                 request.setAttribute("flagEditError", "notSuccess");
               }
               request.getRequestDispatcher("product.jsp").forward(request, response);
               response.sendRedirect("product.jsp");`

Comment: Either you forward to a JSP, or you redirect to a URL, but not both. Remove the call to forward().

Answer (score 0):

As for my requirement to redirect to the page without the servlet url i used javascript to redirect to the `product.jsp` page as in below code :

```
<script>
location.replace("product.jsp");
</script>
```

Thankyou !